# How are exercises in Senior Year Undergraduate Textbooks meant to be treated?

Tags: books

I am studying Averill M Law's "Simulation Modeling and Analysis". It has 30 questions as exercises for Chapter 1. But our exams never ask for such things. They used to ask "exercises/problems/Numericals" in junior years. I personally love exercises and learn a lot by doing them. But the thing is if I start doing even 15 questions, it'd take me 1 week just to solve them(studying full day). So I don't think that's how they're supposed to be treated.
What should I do? I want to use these exercises to further my understanding of concept, but I don't know how do I do it? And yes, I love unsolved exercises. When I was in 11,12 class, I had the time and I solved >2000 unsolved and >1000 solved examples in those 2 years of physics and only I know how much better that made me a physics student.

Comment: Having taught courses using this particular book, I can tell you that some of the exercises have very short solutions (and should take no more than 5-10 minutes) while others involve a significant amount of computer programming or statistical analysis that will take more time (multiple hours.)  There are far more exercises in the book than any student could reasonably be expected to solve.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the purpose of exercises in textbooks (at any level) are to firm up the ideas in the book, give you practice in actually applying the ideas, and, hopefully, leading you to insights that a more passive approach likely won't.

Think of learning as an active sport, not a spectator sport. If you wanna win, you gotta get in the game. See, for example, the book *The Art of Changing the Brain* by James E Zull

You have been wise to focus on exercises in your past. I suggest that you keep it up. If the exercises/problems are now more challenging then that is a good thing. Do as many as you can manage, even if you can't do them all. In some books there is a progression in difficulty through the exercises. In some, adjacent problems are similar. Try to figure out if having done one, which one is best to next spend time on.

You can also ask a professor which exercises they think will benefit you most if you don't have time for all of them. This is especially valuable if they know you and your work already.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional publishers do tend to push textbook authors to include more-and-more exercises... especially in second and subsequent editions.

This and other mechanisms tend to cause textbook authors to be sure to include every known related exercise. Sure, it would be ideal to know how to address all of them... but it would take a lot of time, as you note. And, I claim, it is not necessary to have done all of them to claim a modest grasp of the ideas. Here we might come to asking whether we want a "perfect (if naive) understanding of chapter one", or, rather, a "fairly good idea about chapters one through five". These are different approaches.

And, in my own experience, I have seen over and over that (even just partially-informed) hindsight makes lots of things completely clear in chapter one, not by directly addressing the formalism, but by finding out later what the *point* was. :)